# kineticjs canvas on a facebook page tab

Tags: facebook, html, html5-canvas, kineticjs, facebook-canvas

I am coding a html5 canvas with kinetic.js and need to run it on a facebook tab or canvas. I have tried adding my html to many different 'html welcome tab' and also tried it in an iframe tab, both ways shows the user inputs and css styling but has no functionality. no keyup, no js color, no upload image..

you can see the canvas in action [here](http://www.TeckStyle.co.uk/progress)

could anyone help with info how to get this working on a facebook page tab?
any help is appreciated, thanks in advance :)